# How to transfer a file using sockets from an android java application to a C# windows application?

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I built an application in java on android that sends the bytes of a .jpg file through a socket and an [Asynchronous Server Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) in C# on windows that receives the bytes and writes them into a .jpg a file. The received file can't be open.

In the java application, which is the client, I used the folowing asynctask class executed on the onCreate:

```
class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {

            final File myFile = new File("//sdcard/DCIM/Camera/img1.jpg");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            s = new Socket(ip,3333);
            OutputStream OS = s.getOutputStream();
            OS.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            OS.flush();
            s.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the C# application I received the data and saved it to a file in the following async callback method that is called when data is received:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int buffLength = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, buffLength);
        totaLength += buffLength;
        buffer.CopyTo(allData, totaLength - 1);

        if (buffLength == 0)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref allData, totaLength);
            File.WriteAllBytes("C: /Users/fxavi/Desktop/img.jpg", allData);
            Console.WriteLine(totaLength);
        }
        else
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), clientSocket);
    }
```

Comment: How many bytes are in the original file? The final C# file? What is `allData`? What is `buffer`?

Comment: Both files are the same size

Comment: How many bytes (exact number) are in the original and new file? What are you trying to do with `buffer.CopyTo(allData, totaLength - 1);`?

Comment: 4122765 on both. Beacuse the bytes are not received all at the same time I have to store them in allData.

Comment: `4122765 on both.` Sorry... I do not believe that.

Comment: That's  the value of totaLength and myFile.length()

Comment: You should compare original file size with resulting file size. Not the value of some variables. Use file explorers to check.

Comment: I've checked using file explores and both files are the value I mentioned

Comment: Then investigate whats different in both files. Just send a plain text file. Its easy to check if the text is transferred correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really stupid after finding the solution for this problem. Which is that `totaLength += buffLength;` should be executed before  `buffer.CopyTo(allData, totaLength);` so that the buffer is copied to the right index.

Answer (score 0):

```
 buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

That will mostly not read the requested amount of bytes.length bytes.

Change that first to

```
int nread =  buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

And compare nread to bytes.length and discover that they are not equal.

Further it is a bad idea to load a file completely in memory. Imagine you want to send a GB file.

Better make a loop where you read a chunck from the input stream and then write that chunck to the output stream.

Comment: I've compared nread with bytes.length and they're both the same value.